# Practice questions

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, reference-works

I would like to know if there are any good textbooks/online resources that include plenty of practice problems with solutions for the following topics: Triple integrals in cylindrical coordinates, double integrals with polar coordinates and integration with spherical coordinates and mainly just multiple integrals.

Thanks